# string getting overwritten after concatenating with another string

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, string-concatenation

I am using subprocess to get a build path on a server by using a findbuild.exe..Some exe that finds builds on server using a build string.
I store the output from findbuild.exe in "out" variable ..shown below

```
process = subprocess.Popen(findBuild_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
out,err  = process.communicate()
```

I parse it to get the build location and discard the rest of it using

```
sblTemp = str((out.partition("Location:       ")[2]).partition("\n")[0])
sblTemp is a network path like \\water\build\12345\123.4\
```

I want to add offset to that like \boot\builds\bin\abc.mbn

So, the final path I want is

```
\\water\build\12345\123.4\boot\builds\bin\abc.mbn
```

I used os.path.join but found out that the string was getting over written by the later offset.
When I am trying to concat the above two, I am seeing that if I do this
`temp = r"XYZ"+ sbl`, it works fine but when I try to do it this way `temp = sblTemp + r"XYZ"` it overwrites the first string

Could you help me figure out what is going wrong here?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Can you please give a small sample of code and tell us what incorrect result it gives?

Comment: sbl has the build path-
temp = ""
temp = sbl + r"HELLO"
print temp 
print ""

temp = ""
temp = r"HELLO" + sbl
print temp

Output: 
HELLOfle\builds41\INTEGRATION\M4004.2

HELLO\\waffle\builds41\INTEGRATION\M4004.2

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going wrong.
The findBuild.exe was adding a carriage return at the end of the string and that was messing up everything. When I added .strip, it works fine :)